# Having difficulty with my string output values--- Beginner problem

Tags: arrays, string

I am currently learning the basics of JS, and am working on a code to return an array of numbers, in the form of a phone number:
phoneInput = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
phoneOutput = (123) 456-7890

I have done the following, but clearly am missing something. Please pardon such a rookie mistake; I am working hard to improve my skills. I would love assistance in what is wrong here-- thank you!

\\
        var numbersL = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

```
function createNumber(numbersL){
var result1 = 0; 
var result2 = 0;
var result3 = 0;
for(var i=0;i<numbersL.length-1; i++);
if(i<=2){
    numbersL[i]= result1;
}
else if(i>=3 && i<= 5) {
    numbersL[i]=result2;
} else {
    numbersL[i]=result3;
}
console.log("("+ result1 + ") " + result2 + "-" + result3);
}
```

\\

Comment: You have used assignment in a wrong way. You are assigning result1, result2, result3 to numbersL[i] . We assign right variable's value to the left variable but not opposite. 
Use this formula to split the numbers:
result1 = numbersL[0]*100+numbersL[1]*10+numbersL[2]
result2 = numbersL[3]*100+numbersL[4]*10+numbersL[5]
result3 = numbersL[6]*1000+numbersL[7]*100+numbersL[8]*10+numbersL[9]

Comment: Thank you so much @shubhgkr! Silly mistake on my end. I appreciate the help.